# CEPH/ RGW encryption with mutliple tenants

Tags: openstack, ceph

I'm currently planning a small OpenStack deployment and I want to use Ceph for object storage (via Rados Gateway) and block storage.

Ceph [supports multitenancy](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/multitenancy/). It also [supports  encryption](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/encryption/) using key management services like vault or barbican. Since I'm using OpenStack anyways I'd like to go with barbican. If I [use barbican](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/barbican/) I have to create a keystone user which is used to access barbican and store the keys. Doesn't that create a security issue, though?

Let's say I have two tenants, Alice and Bob. They create encrypted buckets. But since all of their keys are stored in barbican using a single user (Ceph's) wouldn't I (since I know the ceph user's password) be able to read the keys and decrypt their data?

Generally speaking, is there a supported use case where multiple users can create encrypted buckets and I wouldn't be able to decrypt their data?